# Webform User Contact Form in Block

Tags: 7, webforms

I cant seem to find any solid info on how to do this in the Webform module, is there a function or a module that goes with webforms to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Webforms when created are nodes by default. In drupal 6 there was a module called webform block (http://drupal.org/project/webformblock) this got encorprated into webform with webform 3 (which as your using drupal 7 you will be using, I dont think its even possible to get webform 2.x on D7)

To get the webform as block:

1. Create your webform in a node.
2. Edit the node.
3. Select the Webform tab.
4. Select the Forms settings tab.
5. Select the Forms settings tab.
6. Select Advanced settings.
7. Switch on Available as block.
8. Save configuration.

Source: http://drupal.org/node/1447436

Comment: yeah i tried this but there isnt a option there, ultimately im thinking web form isnt creating the forms by default, it may be d7 core, the way i am seeing the form is through user/"uid"/contact

Comment: what version of webform are you using? perhaps an update will sort this for you

Comment: im using Webform 7.x-3.15

Answer (score 0):

Here's a video to show you how to make a web form block

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p5CLio9_DfU